# their work is enjoying immediate application in law enforcement

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

> I have two questions regarding the following context:

**"Thankfully, scientists are now much closer to understanding how facial recognition works, *with* significance for possible future remedies. In the meanwhile, their work is enjoying immediate application in law enforcement."**

**First**: “with” means “which has”. And “which” refers to a whole sentence, so: 
“The fact that scientists are now much closer to understanding how facial recognition works has significance for possible future remedies.”

**Second**: I don’t know the meaning of the whole bold part. However, I can guess the meanings of the individual words:
Enjoy: Have something as a feature or benefit
Application: practical use or the ability to be used for practical purposes
Work: their discoveries

Maybe the whole means: "the law enforcement is considering the practical use of their discovery because their achievements have many benefits." :) (I know it is totally wrong)

Comment: Good question.  The first sentence is, I think, ungrammatical; your fix (replace "with" with "which has" makes sense.

Comment: "Is enjoying immediate application" means it is already being used.